# Is it possible to install ONLY JBoss AS server tools by URL?

Tags: eclipse, jboss-tools

Is it possible to have an URL to install only JBoss AS tools server from Jboss Tools pack?

I'm preparing an instruction which I should be simple and avoid error options. I found that instruction "find Jboss tools and select JBOSS AS tools" often ends with full installation, what is not correct for me.

For example I can install separated component by URL http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/builds/staging/m2e-apt/all/repo/

I' know that I can install required feature by command line but I prefer install by URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@michaldo, unfortunately, no. When you try to install plugin via link, the first thing Eclipse is looking at is *p2.index* file.
See for more information [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/p2_index):

> For example the example p2.index contents below will cause p2 to look for compositeContent.jar, and if not found, then compositeContent.xml and would skip looking for content.jar or content.xml as it normally would look for them first. (And, then, naturally, if it needed artifacts from that site, would look for compositeArtifacts.jar and if not found compositeArtifacts.xml and would skip looking for artifacts.jar and artifacts.xml).

And features don't have these auxiliary files, that Eclipse p2 can look for and use.
Everything is ok for you with m2e, because it contains only one feature.

Comment: I'm very happy and satisfied that you answered my question, bdshadow, because I got badge Tumbleweed for the question. As I understood the badge is for stupid questions, your answer is a sign that my question is not stupid. And also I am not stupid. You saved my soul. I will never forget it

Answer (score 0):

You can select only the AS tools feature from the Eclipse Market place entry, or from this site:

http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/

While that feature WILL drag in dependent features and plugins, it won't install EVERYTHING in JBoss Tools.

From the Eclipse Marketplace, search for "JBoss" then [deselect all but the JBoss AS feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUFYL.png):

Or using Help > Install New Software ... http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/neon/stable/updates/ ... [select JBoss AS feature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6rT4.png):

It may not be a single file install, but it's a complete one. You'll need about 16M of disk space for the various features and plugins.